# How can i see a dll file functions in ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

I have function names and addresses of a `dll` file. I want to see a function behavior. How can I use this information in `ollydbg`?

[image: dll exort viewer]

Answer (score 0):

ollydbg can load a dll directly 
once it is loaded use call dll export

select the function of interest

follow the call

set breakpoints as needed

use call export with arguments inserted manually and analyze the function